# Better way to add a lot of labels

Tags: python, tkinter, functools

I'm trying to add a lot of text onto a window in tkinter, and I want them to be in a row. Can I do it in a simpler way than what I am doing because it's really annoying to keep adding labels and changing the row every time. ("bingbong" is just an example, instead of those bingbongs I will have different passwords in a row.)

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

def validateLogin(password):
    print(password.get())
    if password.get() == "test":
        newWindow = Tk()
        newWindow.geometry('1800x800')
        newWindow.title("Passwords")
        tkWindow.destroy()
        Label(newWindow, text="bingbong").grid(row=1, column=0)
        Label(newWindow, text="bingbong").grid(row=2, column=0)
        Label(newWindow, text="bingbong").grid(row=3, column=0)
        Label(newWindow, text="bingbong").grid(row=4, column=0)
        Label(newWindow, text="bingbong").grid(row=5, column=0)
        Label(newWindow, text="bingbong").grid(row=6, column=0)
        Label(newWindow, text="bingbong").grid(row=7, column=0)
        Label(newWindow, text="bingbong").grid(row=8, column=0)
    if password.get() != "test":
        Label(tkWindow, text="Wrong password!", fg='red').grid(row=5, column=2)

#window
tkWindow = Tk()
tkWindow.geometry('250x100')
tkWindow.title('Passwords')

#password label and password entry box
passwordLabel = Label(tkWindow,text="Password").grid(row=1, column=0)
password = StringVar()
passwordEntry = Entry(tkWindow, textvariable=password, show='*').grid(row=1, column=2)

validateLogin = partial(validateLogin, password)

#login button
loginButton = Button(tkWindow, text="Login", command=validateLogin).grid(row=4, column=2)

tkWindow.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a loop to create them instead of creating them manually one at a time

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial


words = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "bingbong", "foobar", "foobaz", "foofoo", "barbar"]
def validateLogin(password):
    print(password.get())
    if password.get() == "test":
        newWindow = Tk()
        newWindow.geometry('1800x800')
        newWindow.title("Passwords")
        tkWindow.destroy()
        for index, word in enumerate(words):
            Label(newWindow, text=word).grid(row=index, column=0)

    if password.get() != "test":
        Label(tkWindow, text="Wrong password!", fg='red').grid(row=5, column=2)

#window
tkWindow = Tk()
tkWindow.geometry('250x100')
tkWindow.title('Passwords')

#password label and password entry box
passwordLabel = Label(tkWindow,text="Password").grid(row=1, column=0)
password = StringVar()
passwordEntry = Entry(tkWindow, textvariable=password, show='*').grid(row=1, column=2)

validateLogin = partial(validateLogin, password)

#login button
loginButton = Button(tkWindow, text="Login", command=validateLogin).grid(row=4, column=2)

tkWindow.mainloop()
```

Edit: use enumerate function to access the string value (password in this case) and index simultaneously

Comment: Sorry, I didnt clarify my problem enough, "bingbong" is just an example. Im trying to have different sentences in a row. The program im making is going to hold passwords and I want all the different passwords to be there.